# A pergunta "What is the translation for “over-ordering”?" nao está a ter feedback suficiente da comunidade?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

A pergunta ["What is the translation for “over-ordering”?"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/what-is-the-translation-for-over-ordering) nao parece ter sido muito bem recebida pela comunidade.

O texto atual da pergunta é o seguinte:

> I know that in the sentence:
>
> The reduction of “over-ordering” was great for our results!
>   "over-ordering" can be translated as "Encomenda excessiva" but what if
>   we are talking about over-ordering food at a McDonalds?

Quando eu li esta pergunta vi que aquilo que o @Hugo pretendia era uma tradução de alguém de comprou comida a mais no McDonalds. Aliás, na minha opinião isso está bem explicito na pergunta:

> what if we are talking about over-ordering food at a McDonalds

Eu não sei dizer se a minha resposta é boa ou não, mas aquilo que me parece é que as outras respostas presentes respondem ao outro uso mencionado pelo perguntador:

> The reduction of “over-ordering” was great for our results!
>   "over-ordering" can be translated as "Encomenda excessiva"

Mas isto é algo que o perguntador já sabe, mais uma vez reivindico que aquilo que o perguntador quer saber é o outro uso. É claro a interpretação
 da pergunta pode não ser feita da mesma forma por toda a gente, por isso seria bom ler o que vocês tem a dizer sobre o assunto.

Eu apelava aos votos, sejam eles negativos ou positivos nas respostas e na pergunta.

Comment: Eu não sou um expert no que toca ao inglês, mas pelo que vi parece-me que tens razão.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu fui reconfirmar [na comunidade inglesa](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374493/can-say-that-i-over-ordered-food-in-a-restaurant-as-a-client)

Answer (score 2):

## A pergunta não é clara

Eu acho que não é claro qual é a pergunta, e que ela pode ser:

1. Tanto sobre "*o gestor encomendou demasiado stock de comida*";
2. Como sobre "*o cliente encomendou demasiada comida*".

E justifico isto com:

1. Eu não tenho a *certeza* de qual ela seja, e por isso deixei um pedido de esclarecimento.
   Acho que sei, mas sem o autor confirmar não posso ter certeza.
2. Para além disso, há respostas tanto acerca de um dos significados possíveis como sobre o outro, o que indica que não é *óbvio* qual o significado da pergunta.

A pergunta precisa de ser melhorada.
Como está, acho que não se pode decidir se uma resposta é boa.

## O autor precisa de clarificar

Acho que o autor deve clarificar a pergunta; e que se não o fizer, a pergunta deve ser fechada.

Eu estou-lhe a dar algum tempo desde que fiz o meu comentário, e se depois disso ainda não tiver sido clarificada então devo votar para fechar a pergunta por ser «*unclear what you're asking*».
(Dei desconto por ser fim-de-semana.)

## Não reconfirmaste

Confirmaste uma das interpretações, mas não confirmaste nem negaste a outra.

Sabemos então apenas que a frase da pergunta *pode* ser interpretada de uma das 2 maneiras, mas não sabemos *que não pode* ser interpretada da outra.

Comment: Se quiseres fazer um update de acordo com edit que foi feito á pergunta agradeco.